# ElementTree, .set() and iteration

Tags: python, xml, iteration, elementtree

This is my first post on Stack Overflow and am a novice programmer.

I am having trouble using ElementTree and the .set() method. Using an f-string I am able to assign recipe_id with the correct number.

When I try to set the recipe_name attribute, it returns only the last element in the name_list array. I'm a bit lost! I'm sure it's something in my syntax or just my understanding of how I'm actually iterating through the items...I just don't understand because the recipe_id portion works just fine.

Expected output (within the XML)

```
<recipes recipe_id="1" recipe_name="Apples">
<recipes recipe_id="2" recipe_name="Oranges">
```

Instead I get:

```
<recipes recipe_id="1" recipe_name="Oranges">
<recipes recipe_id="2" recipe_name="Oranges">
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import os.path 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filename = "my_recipes.xml"
xmlTree = ET.parse(filename)
root = xmlTree.getroot()

#change the recipe id in recipes 
i = 0 
for element in root.iter("recipes"):
    i += 1
    element.set('recipe_id', f"{i}")
 
 #for every tbody in the tree
name_list = []
for tbody in root.iter("tbody"):
    #for every time you find a row 
    for row in tbody.findall('row'):
        data = row.find('entry').text
        #get those rows attribs
        rec_name = row.find('entry').attrib
        #if the row is the row that i want (contains the recipe name)...i couldn't figure out a better way to get this value precisely
        if rec_name == {'namest': 'c1', 'nameend': 'c2', 'align': 'left', 'valign': 'bottom'}:
            #yoink name and stick it in name_list
            name_list.append(data)
 
for recipes in root.findall('recipes'):
    for i in range(len(name_list)):
        recipes.set('recipe_name', F"{name_list[i]}")
 
xmlTree.write(filename, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Root>
    <recipes>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry namest="c1" nameend="c2" align="left" valign="bottom">Apples</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </recipes>
    <recipes>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry namest="c1" nameend="c2" align="left" valign="bottom">Oranges</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </recipes>
</Root>
```

FIXED:
The code should be

```
for i,recipes in enumerate(root.findall('recipes')):
    recipes.set('recipe_name',name_list[i])
```

and I am just stupid.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you try to do?

Comment: I should be seeing something like: <recipes recipe_id="1" recipe_name="Recipe 1"> and <recipes recipe_id="2" recipe_name="Recipe 2"> but instead all recipe_name="Recipe 2" upon output. The ultimate goal is to import this into InDesign as a nicely formed table. (I have many, many recipes in my source XML.)

Comment: No. Explain what you try to do, not how you try to do it. Assume you pass the task to someone else and you should come with a good explanation.

Comment: Okay. I have an XML file with tons and tons of <recipe> tags. I want the program to locate the space in the XML that contains the name of the recipe, and create two separate attributes in the <recipe> tags, recipe_id which gets a # and a recipe_name attribute which is equal to the name found in the XML. Only the <recipe> tags should be modified.

Comment: OK.. now post the **minimal** xml that you have as input and the requested output.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: *My XML:* is the input? What is the requested output based on *My XML:*?

Comment: I see that the issue was solved. Great. (BTW - I made your code even simpler)

Comment: Bryan: If you have a solution, post it as an Answer. Do not put the solution in the Question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.